# Unable to append a vector in a mutex to another vector

Tags: rust, mutex

I have a `Vec<String>` object that's being shared between threads via an `Arc<Mutex>`. I want to take its current value and append it to another vector elsewhere and then clear it:

```
use std::thread;
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};

struct Store {
    lines: Vec<String>
}

fn main() {
    let mut store = Store { lines: vec![] };

    let lines = Arc::new(Mutex::new(vec!["Initial value".to_string()]));
    let lines_clone = lines.clone();

    let t2 = thread::spawn(move || {
        // populate lines
    });

    let t1 = thread::spawn(move || {
        let mut lines_result = lines_clone.lock().unwrap();
        store.lines.extend(lines_result); // This will not work
        lines_result.clear();
    });

    let _ = t1.join();
    let _ = t2.join();
}
```

`extend` won't work because `lines_result` is actually a `MutexGuard` object. I can iterate over the object and append each element, but considering I'm clearing its values before it goes out of scope, is there a more efficient way?

Comment: You could also use `mem::replace(&mut *lines_result, Vec::new())` to move out the vector from behind a `&mut` and replace it with an empty one.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could [use `Vec::drain()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.drain) to move out all its content into an iterator, so you could use it in `.extend()` and at the same time clearing the original vector.

```
move || {
    let mut lines_result = lines_clone.lock().unwrap();
    store.lines.extend(lines_result.drain(..));
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`Vec::append()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.append) to move all elements from one vector onto the end of another.

```
store.lines.append(&mut lines_clone.lock().unwrap());
```

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the error you get:

```
error: the trait bound `std::sync::MutexGuard<'_, std::vec::Vec<std::string::String>>: std::iter::Iterator` is not satisfied [--explain E0277]
  --> <anon>:20:21
   |>
20 |>         store.lines.extend(lines_result); // This will not work
   |>                     ^^^^^^
note: `std::sync::MutexGuard<'_, std::vec::Vec<std::string::String>>` is not an iterator; maybe try calling `.iter()` or a similar method
note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::iter::IntoIterator` for `std::sync::MutexGuard<'_, std::vec::Vec<std::string::String>>`
```

So as you say, `MutexGuard` isn't an `Iterator`.  Much of the time, i.e. when you're calling a method on it, you can use a `MutexGuard<T>` in place of a `T` because it implements `Deref<T>` and the compiler will automatically dereference when needed.

So one option is to explicitly dereference:

```
store.lines.extend(&*lines_result);
```

This (partly) works because `&*lines_result` is a reference to the underlying `Vec`, which implements `IntoIterator`.  However, I think it's more idiomatic and clear to call the `iter` method (which is effectively what the compiler will do with `IntoIterator`:

```
store.lines.extend(lines_result.iter());
```

However, this still doesn't compile as this iterator returns references to the contents, not the actual `String`s.  So we could work around this by asking for them to be cloned too:

```
store.lines.extend(lines_result.iter().cloned());
```

And this works, but is inefficient - it's allocating a new copy of each `String` in the `Vec`, just before discarding the originals anyway.  This is (as another answer has said) exactly what [`Vec::drain()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.drain) is for; it *moves* some or all of the items of the `Vec` into a new iterator which yields the values (not references).  `v.drain(..)` (using the `..` full range) takes all of them in one go, giving the final:

```
store.lines.extend(lines_result.drain(..));
```